# Filter a dictionary with keys coming from a list in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary named "libraries" and I want to loop on the items in the dictionary using a list of keys as a filter.

I don't want to loop on all the items on the dictionary. I want to loop on the items which key matches with a list of predefined keys.

I know how to query the dictionary with a single key using `when` but I can't figure out how to query with multiple values coming from a list.

```
loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.dict', libraries) }}"
when: "'aaa' in item.key"
```

Instead I would like something like this work

```
loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.dict', libraries) }}"
when: "item.key in {{ customListOfKeys }}"
```

How can I make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the list, and then use `item` to find the corresponding value:

```
- debug:
    msg: "The value of {{ item }} is {{ libraries[item] }}
  loop: "{{ customListOfKeys }}"
```

Comment: Many thanks, looping on the list of keys instead of the library items did the job

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"How to query with multiple values coming from a list?"***

A: This is what [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#extract-keys-from-a-dictionary-matching-elements-from-a-list) is for

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ customListOfKey|map('extract', libraries) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    libraries:
      aaa: 1
      bbb: 2
      ccc: 3
    customListOfKey: [aaa, ccc]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ customListOfKey|map('extract', libraries) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => 
  msg: 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) => 
  msg: 3

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```